# DateType field - only possible to select days after today

Tags: php, input, symfony-forms, symfony

I have a form to place an order where you can select (amongst other):

- date takout
- hour takeout

It looks like this:

[image]

The code of the part of my form that includes the following is like this:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($order)
    ->add('dateTakeout', DateType::class, array('label' => "Kies uw datum voor afhaling *", 'required' => true))
    ->add('hourTakeout', TimeType::class, array('label' => "Kies het gewenste uur van afhalen *", 'required' => true));
```

But now I would like that you can only **select the day after today** + **only between 3 PM till midnight**.

But I have no clue on how to foresee this in the form. Can someone help me on my way?

**UPDATE:**

I would like to limit the number of options in my dropdown. So they can't choose a day like 21 june 2016 or a time like 1 pm.

Comment: Do you want to limit those hours or validate whether they are in the range --> these two choices are different approaches. So it depends on your approach and what is acceptable.

Comment: @AlvinBunk, I would like to limit the possibilities.So they can't choose a day like 21 june 2016 or a time like 1 pm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this:

You could get the current Date, then like above in your controller see if the Date is in the Future (let's say July 1). Then create a Flashbag message and redirect to a Flash twig template.

For the hours, you could also do the same thing where you check that the Hours (plus minutes) are within the time range you specified, and if not create a Flash error message and redirect to twig.

An alternate option (which is harder - potentially a lot more code) is to create a form class based on a Entity which is your Date Time objects. Ideally just one Entity containing both date & time. I cannot make suggestions for you on this, but I have not tried this; but I know that this should be possible.

[Forms Classes are explained in this link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes).

I hope this answers the question?

Edit #2.
After going over your question a second time, I see you could do this with the TimeType::class Field:

```
->add('hourTakeout', TimeType::class, array(
        'label' => "Kies het gewenste uur van afhalen *",
        'required' => true,
        'widget' => 'choice',
        'hours' => range(15,23),
        ));
```

This limits your selectable hours from 3PM - 11PM (I put in 24 hour format using the range function. This is a fix for the hours only.
Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Did this help you at all?